# How to get such a frame?

Tags: frame

How to draw such a box in Latex?
According to google, I tried the below method. When multi-line text appears, the text cannot be displayed left-aligned.
And the distance between the text and the upper and lower borders is also very large.

Is there any way? Thanks! ! !

```
\fbox{%
    \parbox{0.42\textwidth}{%
        \begin{center}
        \raggedleft
          This is a test.
        \end{center}
    }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: `\raggedleft` means right-aligned.  Get rid of it.  And `center` does what it says.  Left aligned is the default in a `\parbox`.

Comment: @Gerrie: Can you provide the community with a better title to your question? Asking "How can I get [this]?" doesn't anyone.

Comment: Just in case you don't have it: This Wikibook on Latex can replace a google search many times:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . Also, use this sites search capabilities, which also inludes the "Related" links to the right.

Comment: `center` also adds space above and below.  In this case, it is used purely to add extra space (see also \fboxsep).  The `trivlist` environment would have been simpler.  Does google actually provide LaTeX help or just point you to bad (but popular) advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy thing is:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
...
\end{framed}
```